# Text-Based-Graphics not updating correctly

Tags: c++

so this is kinda hard to explain but I will do my best.

I am making a rpg(ish) game using the Cmd on windows for graphics. I am basically just making walls and a player right now and updating him and redrawing the screen.

my problem is that movement works perfect except when I attempt to hold the "Down" key down. there is a short pause and then the player 'jumps' to the bottom of the screen. I have no idea why this is happening and cannot seem to single my problem down to a narrow part of my code so here is all of it (still not a lot of code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define HEIGHT 25
#define WIDTH 80

using namespace std;

void boardLogic();
void renderBoard();
void render();

int seed = 0;
int GameSpeed = 150;
int MovementSpeed = 1500;
bool stopped = false;
bool doneRendering = false;


char board[83][83] = {"###############################################################################",
                      "#1                                                                            #",
                      "#2 @                                                                          #",
                      "#3                                                                            #",
                      "#4                                                                            #",
                      "#5                                                                            #",
                      "#6                                                                            #",
                      "#7                                                                            #",
                      "#8                                                                            #",
                      "#9                                                                            #",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "###############################################################################",
                      "#                                                                             #",
                      "#1                                                                            #",
                      "#2                                                                            #",
                      "#3                                                                            #",
                      "#4                                                                            #",
                      "#5                                                                            #",
                      "###############################################################################",

                     };


int main()

{
    system("Color 3");

    while(stopped == false)
    {
        boardLogic();
        system("cls");
        render();
        Sleep(GameSpeed);
    }
}

void renderBoard()
{
    srand(seed);


    for(int x = 0; x < 24; x++)
    {
        cout << board[x];

        for(int y = 0; y < 84; y++)
        {
            if(board[x][y] == '#') board[x][y] = 219;

        }
        cout << endl;

    }
}

void boardLogic()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 24; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 84; y++)
        {
            if(board[x][y] == '#') board[x][y] = 219;
            if(board[x][y] == '@' && doneRendering == true)
            {
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
                {
                    if(board[x-1][y] == ' ')
                    {
                        board[x-1][y] = '@';
                        board[x][y] = ' ';
                        break;
                    }
                    Sleep(MovementSpeed);
                    break;
                }
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0)
                {
                    if(board[x][y+1] == ' ')
                    {
                        board[x][y+1] = '@';
                        board[x][y] = ' ';
                        break;
                    }
                    Sleep(MovementSpeed);
                    break;
                }
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) != 0)
                {
                    if(board[x][y-1] == ' ')
                    {
                        board[x][y-1] = '@';
                        board[x][y] = ' ';
                        break;
                    }
                    Sleep(MovementSpeed);
                    break;
                }
                if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
                {
                    if(board[x+1][y] == ' ')
                    {
                        board[x+1][y] = '@';
                        board[x][y] = ' ';
                        break;
                    }
                    Sleep(MovementSpeed);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
}

void render()
{
    doneRendering = false;
    renderBoard();
    doneRendering = true;
}
```

Comment: dos.h and conio.h are old headers that shouldn't really be used anymore. `#define` is completely unnecessary and unsafe when there are better alternatives. `using namespace std;` is also bad - just prefix what you use. Global variables are a big no-no - use parameters and return values. `system` calls are generally bad and can be implemented with API functions specifically designed for that. C++ has `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, so no need for `Sleep`.   A boolean tested as a condition should not have `==` or `!=`, it should either be `b` or `!b`. `srand` should not be called every render.

Comment: You have magic numbers all over the place. As is, `doneRendering` cannot be false in `boardLogic`, which makes the whole variable dead code. The result of `GetAsyncKeyState` should be masked with 0x8000 to check for a key being down. Finally, it's possible to forgo tracking global input for no particular reason by (and it's harder than it should be because of your console decision) `SetConsoleMode` and `ReadConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the logic for the down-event is not the same as the others, have you tried to change it so it's similar to the up for instance? i.e. remove the call to render.

Comment: yes I have. sorry I edited my question with the correct code. Yes I still have the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

I solved my issue by using switch statements instead of "if"s. I have no idea why this worked but it does in fact work perfectly.

Comment: Randomly changing parts of code without consideration is not a good thing.